# Trouble with setting reference category on logistic regression interaction variable

Tags: r, logistic-regression, interaction, categorical

Among the variables in my dataset, I want to test the interaction between two variables- state category and purpose.

- state.ctgry has two ordinal categories (NDA and Non NDA)
- Purporse has 5 ordinal categories (Social, Economic, Cultural, Religious and Educational)

I want to keep NDA interactions as the reference category and get the non-NDA interaction results displayed in my log reg. In my plain purpose variable, I had defined "economic" as at the reference category. I am interested in the religious, social and cultural interactions with non NDA in my result

> Despite defining the category, I still see the results for the NDA interaction with non-NDA interaction treated as the reference category ([Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4BNd.png) )
>
> ```
> Regdcanceled$state.ctgry <- as.factor(Regdcanceled$state.ctgry)
> Regdcanceled$Purpose <- as.factor(Regdcanceled$Purpose)
>
> # set category 1 of variable A as reference
> Regdcanceled$state.ctgry <- relevel(Regdcanceled$state.ctgry, ref = "NDA")
>
> # set category X of variable B as reference
> Regdcanceled$Purpose <- relevel(Regdcanceled$Purpose, ref = "Economic")
>
> # create the interaction variable with NDA as the reference category
> Regdcanceled$Int <- interaction(Regdcanceled$state.ctgry, Regdcanceled$Purpose, 
>                                 drop = TRUE)
>
> # Fit logistic regression model with all levels of the interaction variable
> log.fit4 <- glm(Cancelled ~ Purpose + state.ctgry + Total.amount + Int, 
>                 data = Regdcanceled, family = binomial)
> summary(log.fit4)
> ```

Comment: Look at the help for formula (`?formula`) to understand how to add interaction terms to a regression model using the `*` or `:` operators.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You add interactions by using `*`. The reference category stems from the reference category of your interaction variables. Thus you would have to alter your code like this:

```
log.fit4 <- glm(Cancelled ~ Purpose*state.ctgry + Total.amount, 
                data = Regdcanceled, family = binomial)
```